# Is there any Software package to confirm correctness of your derivation steps?

Tags: math-software, computer-algebra-systems, computer-assisted-proofs

Suppose I made a very complicated (not necessarily difficult) derivations in which it is very likely for anyone to make some silly mistakes, e.g., incorrect sign, overlooking a term, and so on.

I wonder if there is a software package that verifies every step of my work against this kind of mistakes.

Let me give you an over-simplified example of what I am looking for, or what I expect the software to do for me. Suppose I want to solve the linear equation:

$x+10=2x+1$

I want the software to kind of take this step as input, and verify that my next step is implied from the first step. For example:

For example, if I write $x+10 - 10 = 2x + 1 + 10$ as implication of the first step, the software should tell me it's wrong, regardless of why. However, if my step was a correct implication of the first step, the software should assure its correctness. It might also be very useful if there is a third alternative in which the software can not decide if the implication is correct or wrong (could this be logically possible?).

Answer (score 0):

[Aplusix](http://www.aplusix.com/en/%20'Aplusix) is a software to do this kind of things in the context of education.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This software helps a lot with basic arithmetic and algebra, but does not do too much beyond that. For example, it does not help in vector/matrix calculus, ODE/PDE analytical solution verification, ... etc.